# How to zoom simultaneously on two ImageViews?

Tags: android, android-imageview, zooming

I want to tap&zoom simultaneously two ImageViews at the same time. In other words, I would like to zoom the left view and see the exact same effect in the other ImageView without any lag.

Is there are library that already does it? I've looked around a lot without any success :(

Thanks

Comment: What mechanims do you use to "zoom", on the first ImageViews ?

Comment: I'm currently using a modified version of PhotoView ( https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView ) but I can change the library if it's needed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To actually make it work (without flying... if you could do it with flying would be great) I have to override PhotoViewAttacher methods and link them toghether. Actually I didn't want only the scale option to be relaunched, but the drag too. I did it this way:

```
private boolean DEBUG = true;
private boolean actionL = false;
private boolean actionR = false;
private boolean scalingL = false;
private boolean scalingR = false;

//[...]

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    photoViewAttacherL = new PhotoViewAttacher(photoL){
        @Override
        public void onDrag(float dx, float dy) {
            if (!scalingL && !actionL) {
                actionL = true;
                if (DEBUG) Dbg.d("DRAG", "x: " + dx + " y: " + dy);
                photoViewAttacherR.onDrag(dx, dy);
                super.onDrag(dx, dy);
                actionL = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFling(float startX, float startY, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                scalingL = false;
                scalingR = false;
            }
            return super.onTouch(v, ev);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScale(float scaleFactor, float focusX, float focusY) {
            if (!actionL) {
                actionL = true;
                if (DEBUG)
                    Dbg.d("SCALE", "factor: " + scaleFactor + " x: " + focusX + " y: " + focusY);
                scalingL = true;
                photoViewAttacherR.onScale(scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
                super.onScale(scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
                actionL = false;
            }
        }
    };

    photoViewAttacherR = new PhotoViewAttacher(photoR){
        @Override
        public void onDrag(float dx, float dy) {
            if (!scalingR && !actionR) {
                actionR = true;
                if (DEBUG) Dbg.d("DRAG", "x: " + dx + " y: " + dy);
                photoViewAttacherL.onDrag(dx, dy);
                super.onDrag(dx, dy);
                actionR = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFling(float startX, float startY, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                scalingL = false;
                scalingR = false;
            }
            return super.onTouch(v, ev);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScale(float scaleFactor, float focusX, float focusY) {
            if (!actionR) {
                actionR = true;
                if (DEBUG)
                    Dbg.d("SCALE", "factor: " + scaleFactor + " x: " + focusX + " y: " + focusY);
                scalingR = true;
                photoViewAttacherL.onScale(scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
                super.onScale(scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
                actionR = false;
            }
        }
    };

//[...]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually it's pretty simple with [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) you are using:

Layout `activity_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And code inside activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo1);
    ImageView pic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);

    Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    pic1.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
    pic2.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher1 = new PhotoViewAttacher(pic1);
    final PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher2 = new PhotoViewAttacher(pic2);
    photoViewAttacher1.setOnScaleChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnScaleChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScaleChange(float v, float v1, float v2) {
            photoViewAttacher2.onScale(v, v1, v2);
        }
    });
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is great! The only problem is that if I zoom and "move around" the image tapping on it the other images doesn't replicate the behaviour. Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Imageview i suggest you to to see the [Matrix.mapreact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapRect%28android.graphics.RectF%29) and work with perticuler matrix of image

**OR**

you can also use [GestureImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview)

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        GestureImageView view = new GestureImageView(this);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        layout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't understood in the code example how you handle the second image. Is there only one, right?